# How to scrape a web page's CSS line contents using a loop, and separate out the contents

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the following web page, and I encountered some issues that I couldn't solve. As a fish in scraping, I didn't get deep into the beautiful soup nor html, css. I am just browsing some tutorials but the examples they show are not deep enough to cover practical issues.

So, here is the page: https://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/22-2016/matches/861695/team-stats/6339/0_SHOT_01#tabs-wrapper-anchor

What I am trying to do is to extract web pages' css line's x1, x2, y1, y2 coordinates values and save them in the corresponding columns x1,x2,y1,y2 in a dataset.

[image]

These elements correspond to the arrows on the webpage.
[image]

I've tried to extract the overall container using find id:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

page = requests.get("https://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/22-2016/matches/861695/team-stats/6339/0_SHOT_01#tabs-wrapper-anchor")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

match_view = soup.find(id="match-view-container")
pitch_obj = match_view.find_all('line', class_="pitch-object")
# to print out the first pitch_object
print(pitch_obj[0])
print(type(pitch_obj[0]))
print(pitch_obj[1])
info = [print(pitch_obj[i]) for i in pitch_obj]
print(info)
```

The question is that, these different line in css has different class name, such as pitch-object timer-1-24, and pitch-object timer-1-26. I only know to get the following results from the codes above, but do not know how to extract the x1, x2, y1, and y2.

```
<line class="pitch-object timer-1-24" marker-end="url(#bigyellow)" marker-start="url(#bigyellowend)" style="stroke:yellow;stroke-width:3" x1="393.52" x2="373.76" y1="234.79" y2="157.941"></line>
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
<line class="pitch-object timer-1-26" marker-end="url(#bigblue)" marker-start="url(#bigblueend)" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:3" x1="283.28" x2="338.4" y1="193.97" y2="164.14"></line>
```

Plus I cannot loop over the pitch_obj to extract info from the different lines.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Tag
```

Is there a better way to extract the x1, x2, y1, and y2 from all the css line elements in this web page and put them into separated columns in a dataset? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip()` and BeautifulSoup's CSS selector to combine tags you are looking for (e.g. `svg.select('[x1]')` will find all tags with `x1` attribute):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/22-2016/matches/861695/team-stats/6339/0_SHOT_01#tabs-wrapper-anchor'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

svg = soup.select_one('svg#pitch')

info = []
for x1, y1, x2, y2 in zip(svg.select('[x1]'), svg.select('[y1]'), svg.select('[x2]'), svg.select('[y2]')):
    info.append((x1['x1'], y1['y1'], x2['x2'], y2['y2']))

for i, (x1, y1, x2, y2) in enumerate(info):
    print("line={}:\tx1={} y1={} x2={} y2={}".format(i+1, x1, y1, x2, y2))
```

This prints coordinates for each line found in the SVG:

```
line=1: x1=393.52 y1=234.79 x2=373.76 y2=157.941
line=2: x1=283.28 y1=193.97 x2=338.4 y2=164.14
line=3: x1=250 y1=476.57 x2=267.68 y2=435.75
line=4: x1=176.16 y1=283.46 x2=190.72 y2=270.9
line=5: x1=358.16 y1=277.18 x2=417.44 y2=133.469
line=6: x1=238.56 y1=299.16 x2=312.4 y2=258.34
line=7: x1=252.08 y1=291.31 x2=340.48 y2=192.4
```

Comment: Jesus christ, man, you are a genius! You just saved my whole day....I'll go ahead and study your codes!

Comment: @commentallez-vous Better not look at my code ;) Just look at CSS Selectors(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), they are quite handy. Albeit BeautifulSoup doesn't support all of them

Comment: I gotta question..I didn't understand the 'svg#pitch'..what does the # here mean? Also, when using svg.select, why would you write '[x1]' instead of x1. I went to check the page content, it was written as x1, and since I didn't learn CSS at all.. I am somehow lost here..could you please give me a rope?

Comment: @commentallez-vous `svg#pitch` will select all `svg` tags, where `id="pitch"`, in your case there's only one in whole document. The `[x1]`, x1 in square brackets means that you want to select all tags that has x1 attribute, such as <line x1="...">. If you want to select only `<div>` tags with `x1` attribute, you will write `select('div[x1]')`

Comment: I just watched a tutorial, and it says that when selecting id, you need to add a # in front of the id, so select_one(svg#pitch) means selecting svg with id pitch....

Comment: Got it man, thank you very much for your explanation and help. I really appreciate it, and gotta watch some CSS selectors tutorials!